# What is the "Maintenance" amount referring to on the bitcoin exchange Bitcoinica?

Tags: trading

I have tried out Bitcoinica, and although it is complicated i like it a lot!

What confused me is the "Maintenance" amount shown in the Account overview. It looks like it is not explained on the website.

If it is the fee, it is quite steep, i must say..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it relates to when you have a margin call for your open positions. From [their FAQ:](https://www.bitcoinica.com/pages/faq)

> What's your Margin Call Policy?
>
> After you've logged in, you can immediately see your real-time account
>   Net Value (total assets) and Maintenance (minimum net value). When
>   your Net Value falls below twice the amount of Maintenance, we will
>   issue a margin call. If you don't take actions before your Net Value
>   falls below Maintenance, all your positions will be liquidated
>   automatically.

Comment: i do not have open any positions or orders at the moment, yet i have Maintenance $52.23 Margin Balance $261.17. edit: now i got it.  Maintenance is always Balance/5 since it is currently trading with a leverage of 1:5.

Comment: hmm, well based on their FAQ, and the general use of maintenance margin requirements on other Forex sites, that is what it should refer to.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_%28finance%29#Initial_and_maintenance_margin_requirements